# How can I configure GitHub to accept files via email?

Tags: github

I've got systems that we version the configs on, which are capable of e-mailing the configs out automatically periodically.  Obviously with a document management system (such as Alfresco via SMTPInbound/NodeID) it's possible.

Can GitHub Enterprise be configured also to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github says this is not possible; there's no way to have GitHub accept an email to update files in a repo.  Any automation that you set up would involve a separate working copy of the Git repository. That's definitely possible but would have to be set up outside GitHub.